# register Google Analytics using C#

Tags: c#, logging, google-analytics

I am trying to get data from Google Analytics using their api.
[I have found this great post about doing it with C#](http://www.stickler.de/en/information/code-snippets/analytics-api.aspx)

The thing is when I use its example I can get data from Analytics only if I am already logged on to Google with my business user/pass, otherwise it will direct me to the login page.

What I want is to prevent my marketing personal from knowing the user/pass info, and I don't want them to view all business related data in  Analytics.

I want to let them get the data from my admin site without exposing the business Google account even if they are currently logged on with their private gmail or whatever google service their using at the moment.

Hope I was clear enough.

Comment: How are you going to provide your account details using your website? Are you going to write the details in a file?

Comment: This is what i don't understand. How do i do it programmicly.i was  hopping someone already used this api and know it. I assuming there is some method in it where i should provide the login details.

Comment: Okay, what about a MySQL server? Why don't you create a `Server` application that receives sockets from the `Client` then based on the client's request, the server processes MySQL queries returning for the client what is desired? (i.e You have your own server application with port 4444 opened. A client sends data to this port and the server replies with the username/password from the MySQL server). Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add those users to Google Analytics? They can be given a restricted access.

http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1699665

http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1009702

Comment: That's because they are not so tech and can't understand how to make filters and view, and use the analytics in general. I wan't to have full control on the views their getting and how it is presented.

Comment: As Users they will have a read-only access to the reports you create.